# Why does wp_insert_term return WP_Error / Invalid Taxonomy when the taxonomy exists?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm calling `wp_insert_term` in my code, and the result is a `WP_Error` instance.

It seems this would be the result if the taxonomy does not exist.

So I added a line prior to `wp_insert_term`...

```
if (taxonomy_exists('the_taxonomy')) {
    error_log('it exists');
}
```

And in my log output, I see `it exists`.

So, what other reasons might `wp_insert_term` give me an error as a result?

Maybe I should also mention that I'm running this code in a stand-alone script.

I have also gone to the place in my code where the taxonomy is registered, and put an `echo 'here';` statement to make sure that file is being executed at the right time, and it is. I see `here` in my log before any other output, so that leads me to believe the taxonomy definitely exists.

Comment: `<?php wp_insert_term( $term, $taxonomy, $args = array() ); ?>`

Error handling is assigned for the nonexistence of the `$taxonomy` and `$term` parameters before inserting.

Comment: I'm looking at the term name (first arg), and the taxonomy key (second arg), and they're just normal strings. One of the values it's getting caught on is just the string "VENDOR". Are there requirements on the case of the term name?

Comment: Ah, I found the problem, the key was invalid. I was building the key from a string + another variable, and the variable was undefined.